# How to return null instead of empty string when nothing selected for vue-select

Tags: vuejs2, vue-select

I want to return `null` when nothing is selected instead of `""`. With the `reduce` function below it still returns `""`.  Note that also if something is selected it needs to return the object but with ONLY the `id` field in it.

```
<v-select v-model="answer"
  :placeholder="Pick one (or not)"
  :options="[{id: 1, label: 'A'}, {id: 2, label: 'B'}]"
  :reduce="entry => (entry === '' ? null : {id: entry.id})">
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well (duh) the answer is that if they don't select anything, then it doesn't touch the variable referenced in `v-model`, so it retains whatever value it originally had - which in my case was `""`. Just initializing it to `null` fixed everything.